# Bing WPF Custom Pushpin Template Overlapping

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, bing-api

I am using the Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF dll in c# WPF.

Here is my issue in the picture below:

[image]

I use a custom template for the pushpin because I need to display some simple information for it. There is no infobox in the WPF version to my knowledge.

Clustering the pushpins together in one is not an option for me, because the pushpins represent a delivery location which needs to be displayed on the map. Zooming out is not an option for me because there could be a delivery on the other side of town which all need to be displayed by a bounding box including all pushpins.

Here is the code for my custom pushpin template:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="RedPushPinTemplate" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
        <Grid >

            <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{TemplateBinding  Content}" Canvas.ZIndex="2"  Height="75" Width="65" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>

        <Rectangle Width="35" Height="50" Margin="0 35 0 0" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
            <Rectangle.Fill >
                <ImageBrush  ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/redpin.jpg"/>

            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My question is, is there anyway to write code for the template that detects an overlap and do something nice to display the information for both pins. Better yet, is there an infobox control that someone is aware of that has this functionality built in?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You want to display several Pushpins with a delta X/Y or a new Template with several information bundled into a new template? This is very important for the Solution :)

Comment: I want to somehow shift the text part of the template over or find a new solution which would allow me to display the information without overlapping

Comment: @Johannes Wanzek Server pushpins with a delta x/y, sorry I misunderstood your question at first

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer.

How many Pushpins do you have? One Possiblity is to compare the List of Items (X&Y Coordinates + Radius) to find out which Pushpins Intersect eachother. Then you can adjust the X value and interate again.

You can also do this on the control level itself attaching a behavior which is constantly looking for pushpins and then see if they intersect.

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to do this with the Control Template? That is exactly what I had planned out logically but I am not sure how to implement it.